# Conjecture about the minimum of the Gamma function

Tags: derivatives, examples-counterexamples, gamma-function, conjectures, constants

Problem/Conjecture:

Let the function :

$$f(x)=\frac{((x+x_{\min})!-(x_{\min})!)^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{\frac{1}{x^2}}}$$

Where $x_\min$ denotes the minimum abscissa of the Gamma function near by $0.4616$

Then do we have :

$$f'(1-x_{\min})<^?0$$

An computation show it could be true.

And what is :

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}(f(x)-f(x-1))=?$$

Is it true? If yes is it trivial or well-know ?

Comment: This is for $\Gamma(x+1)$

Comment: What is the motivation behind this problem?

Comment: @Gary Find an approximative way to evaluate the minimum of the Gamma function

Comment: Euler is back !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Leonard Bean I presume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using for an approximation of $x_{\text{min}}$ the rational values
$$\left\{\frac{343}{743},\frac{379}{821},\frac{2691
   5}{58304},\frac{47381}{102638},\frac{51171}{110848},\frac{102721}{222517},\frac{256992}{556703},\frac{1439231}{3117701}\right\}$$ what is obtained
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & f'(1-x_{\text{min}}) \\
 1 & -0.00011212968 \\
 2 & -0.00001826854 \\
 3 & -0.00001806921 \\
 4 & -0.00001815531 \\
 5 & -0.00001816370 \\
 6 & -0.00001816408 \\
 7 & -0.00001816416 \\
 8 & -0.00001816417 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For the second question, using $x=10^{12}$ to avoid overflows, it is quite impressive
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & f(10^{12})-f(10^{12}-1) \\
 1 & 0.367879441171796089914000535729 \\
 2 & 0.367879441171796086295532027426 \\
 3 & 0.367879441171796086287846671071 \\
 4 & 0.367879441171796086291166324500 \\
 5 & 0.367879441171796086291489671976 \\
 6 & 0.367879441171796086291504586674 \\
 7 & 0.367879441171796086291507556416 \\
 8 & 0.367879441171796086291507768373 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

which is
$$\huge \frac 1 e$$

**Edit**

For the behavior of the difference, assuming that we can neglect $s_{\text{min}}$ and that
$$f(x)-f(x-1) \sim f'(x)$$ using
$$f(x)= \frac{\Gamma (x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{\frac{1}{x^2}} }$$
$$f'(x)= \frac{\Gamma (x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{3+\frac{1}{x^2}} } \left(x^2 \psi
   ^{(0)}(x+1)+2 \log (x)-x \log (\Gamma (x+1))-1\right)$$
$$\log(f'(x))=-1+\frac 1 {2x}+O\left(\left(\frac{\log (x)}{x}\right)^2\right)$$

Comment: See my update  Claude

Comment: You can prove $1/\mathrm{e}$ using Stirling's formula.

Comment: @Gary. Be sure that I tried and ... gave up ! I would enjoy to see an asymptotic of the diffrence. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Gary Can you offer a proof ?

Comment: @ErikSatie Done.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to the second question. We have
$$
((x + x_{\min } )! - (x_{\min } )!)^{1/x}  = (x + x_{\min } )!^{1/x} \left( {1 - \frac{{(x_{\min } )!}}{{(x + x_{\min } )!}}} \right)^{1/x}  \\= (x + x_{\min } )!^{1/x}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right),
$$
and
$$
x^{ - 1/x^2 }  = 1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log x}}{{x^2 }}} \right),
$$
and
$$
(x + x_{\min } )!^{1/x}  \sim \frac{x}{\mathrm{e}},
$$
as $x\to +\infty$. Thus
$$\tag{1}
f(x) = (x + x_{\min } )!^{1/x}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log x}}{x}} \right)
$$
Now, for any fixed $a$,
$$
\Gamma (z + a) = z^{z + a - 1/2} \mathrm{e}^{ - z} \sqrt {2\pi } \left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{z}} \right)} \right)
$$
as $z\to +\infty$. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
(\Gamma (z + a))^{1/z} & = z^{1 + a/z - 1/(2z)} {\rm e}^{ - 1} (2\pi )^{1/z} \left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{z^2 }}} \right)} \right) \\ & = \frac{z}{{\rm e}} + \frac{{a - 1/2}}{{\rm e}}\log z + \frac{{\log (2\pi )}}{{\rm e}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log z}}{z}} \right)
\end{align*}
as $z\to +\infty$. Hence,
$$\tag{2}
(\Gamma (z + a))^{1/z}  - (\Gamma (z - 1 + a))^{1/(z - 1)}  = \frac{1}{{\rm e}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{z}} \right)
$$
as $z\to +\infty$. From $(1)$ and $(2)$ it follows that $f(x)-f(x-1) \to 1/{\rm e}$.

Comment: Great (once more) ! Thanks for posting it.

Comment: Very cool it's nice

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici see the limit at $x\to 0^-$ of  the last difference with $a$ it answers one of your own question with inverse Gamma function.

Comment: @ErikSatie You mean $(2)$? That is valid only for large $z$. It does not describe the behaviour of the difference near $0$.

Comment: @Gary not your result just the difference at limit which is equal to $-1/\Gamma(a)$